# What is the use case for pull request validation in Azure DevOps?

Tags: validation, azure-devops, pull-request

In Azure DevOps build pipelines we have "Continues integration" and "Pull request validation" as a triggering option. If we enable the continues integration it automatically runs CI pipeline whenever we push something new. Why we need the "Pull request validation" option if it always builds the last commit of the source branch. Haven't we got the same with "Continues integration"? I was expecting to have there a build for merge commit, so we could escape the merge related failures on the main development branch.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most teams use a pull request as a code review process. Having the code built with the pull request gives the reviewers stats on the build **without** having to actually merge the code into the targeted branch. If you have a protected branch like `master`, the reviewer(s) can look at build times, unit test coverage and/or compiler warnings without actually making any changes to the `master` branch in Git. Remember that Git is distributed so it is actually possible to merge a breaking change into a branch even though you have CI setup. This step is simply a way to protect and safeguard key branches.

Comment: So, in this way we allow integration to master only via PR. Correct?
The merge button will be disabled if build is failing. Can't we have the same behaviour with CI builds? As I remember CI build status is also visible in PR.

Comment: Yes, you would have to use "Branch Policies" to force merges into master via PR. Yes, CI status is available in the PR but when you do a PR, a special branch gets created with the result of merging the two branches. This helps to highlight merge conflicts, missing forward or reverse integrations and any other issue that can come from a merge. CI is great at catching problems, but won't catch them all. Merging the code and building it is the only true way to be certain hence PR.

Comment: "a special branch gets created with the result of merging the two branches"- I was expecting that behaviour too, but as I can see it just builds the last commit from the source branch. So, if I have some commits in master they will not be included in that PR build.

Comment: I just verified that if you do the PR through the UI, it will include changes from `master`. I created a scenario where I purposely generated a merge conflict and the tool will ask for manual review. These changes are then built by the PR build. Without knowing more about your branching/merging process, I can't say for certain what you should expect. What I can say is if you follow a Gitflow type pattern, it would be in your best interest to build your PR.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Here is the build: https://pasteboard.co/Itqwt5z.png
and I have checked the commit hash there. It was the last commit on my source branch. Also, in my case the main branch name is develop

Comment: Agree with @virusstorm. Validate the changes before pr completed is more security and better way for your branch. It can help you find out the problem before the bad occurred.

Comment: Hi @virusstorm. What kind of source control system do you use? Github?

Comment: @ArsenKhachatryan I use both Azure DevOps Git and GitHub. It just depends on the project.

Comment: I have opened a ticket for Azure Devops support. Seems there is a bug related to the Bitbucket integration.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/715377/pull-request-validation-is-not-woorking-properly-f.html?childToView=738506#comment-738506

Comment: Does it also trigger the release pipeline once the build due to a PR validation succeeds?

Comment: It can, it depends on the artifact filters you have set in the release definition.